# Granite countertop with 1" shims

Tags: kitchen-counters, granite

We are remodeling our condo and replaced a damaged countertop.

The current install has the granite countertop resting on roughly 1" of shims.

Can the granite countertop last 10 years supported in this manner?

[image: shimmed countertop]

Comment: Shim the bottom of the cabinets and use molding/trim to hide them. Also put your shims point-to point, not all pointing the same way like the stack at the corner.

Comment: How big is the kitchen? Can you upload some more pictures? I would be inclined to pull the countertop and set the cabinets correctly.

Comment: your post reads like a rant ... please remove the irrelevant information and focus on the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Is the counter not level, the cabinet not level, or both? I agree that the canonical answer would be to shim beneath cabinet until it is level and supports level counter, them hide the shims behind baseboards/toe-kicks cut to fit.

Answer (score 4):

Countertops are designed to have more consistent support than just a few contact points like in the photo you posted.

The amount of shimming done there is pretty concerning and should be addressed otherwise you risk the countertop cracking.

If this was my kitchen I would pull the countertop and set the cabinets correctly. Without seeing more of the kitchen/countertop it is hard to give a better *plan of attack*.

Comment: 100% for "set the cabinets correctly". Best plan.

Answer (score 1):

The counter will not crack unless it's close to the sink and you get up there and do a pounding dance. The bottom line is that it will look horrible. Raise the cabinet as much as you can while keeping it level and use some quarter round or other trim to cover the remaining gap after you've shimmed the remaining space. Use the levelers on the dishwasher to raise it and shim if needed.

Comment: You don't think an unsupported countertop as show above will not crack? I'd be concerned about unloading heavy groceries and such on the counter. +1 for the quarter round idea to minimize the visible gap though.